# Test Facebook Graph API without Page Public Content Access permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to test an app implemented *Facebook Graph API* required *Page Public Content Access* permission?

I was testing the `{page_id}_{post_id}` endpoint in [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to get a post, but got the error message:

```
This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.
```

This error applies to both *random pages* and *pages that I own*. I couldn't use it at all. The app I've planned to do is mostly based on Facebook posts so I may say this is it's the main function, so I just can't have the app reviewed until I can test this endpoint successfully.
What can I do to make it work? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to test with pages that you own, and use a page access token that encompasses the necessary permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/page/feed#readperms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I chose the wrong type to create my facebook app. I chose to create a "***Business Connected Experiences***" app instead of a "***Manage Business Integrations***" one, so I couldn't fully access to the permissions I need to query on my own page. The former only doesn't provide me the *pages_user_read_content* and the likes, so it was unable for me to read comments from posts. Besides, I also use an user token instead of a *page token* [(Thanks Lars for pointing this out for me)](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/271166704200074/?notif_t=developer_community_forum_thread_update&notif_id=1603554933564183&ref=m_notif&refid=48).

So, I just create a new app with the right type and everything turns out well.

Hope this will help someone someday.