# Facebook Graph API Application Token and permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth, facebook-permissions

My goal is to call the Facebook Graph API for the [product catalog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/products/) endpoints using an Application Token and in **Development Mode**.

Someone seems to have created a specific type of application : [Test Facebook Graph API without Page Public Content Access permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185245/test-facebook-graph-api-without-page-public-content-access-permission/74108108#74108108)

I've created a [business application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types), one not related with a business and one related with a business account. On the first one I couldn't find the catalog_management permission in the "App Review" -> "Permissions and Features", on the second one I could, but I cannot grant it without passing through the Facebook App Review process. It's only for testing purpose, I want to test the endpoints to see what's possible to do.

I managed to make the calls and get the answers with a User Token access_token but I get errors when I try to use an application token "This endpoint requires the 'business_management' permission.." (when I try to access a business object) or "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'NNNNN...' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions" (when I try to access a product catalog object)

Here is an example of request I call using postman that works with an User Token access_token but doesn't with an Application Token :

[https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/ID_PRODUCT_CATALOG/products?access_token={{access_token}}](https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/ID_PRODUCT_CATALOG/products?access_token=%7B%7Baccess_token%7D%7D)

(where ID_PRODUCT_CATALOG is the ID of an existing product catalog)

Do you know if it's possible to test some features / permissions without submitting the application for a review ? I only see "email" and "public_profile" with :
Access level : Advanced Access
API Calls : Ready to Use
App Review Status : Auto Granted
In the "Permissions and Features" section on the Developers Administration

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, then you should just follow these steps:

1. go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. choose your app and find, and select the permissions you need.
3. then press "Generate Access Token"
4. Facebook will ask for your acceptance of newly added permissions

Your issue is that the app does not have the correct rights. Otherwise, you can add these permissions by creating a "log-in flow," but I believe, that my described way is much easier. :)

Comment: How do I get access token programatically with all required permissions? I want access token via a script run as a cron

Answer (score 0):

If you want to experiment with Facebook api you can enable **App Mode: Development** on your Facebook app. Then you can create an access token with the full permissions you want, of course it can only be used by you, with pages you have admin role and only use for you. You can use graph api with that access token

Glad to have helped you

[image]

Comment: Thank you sonnv0812 ; I am already in App Mode: Development.
I've got my user under "Administrators".
When you say "then you can create an access token with the full permissions you want" ; what do you mean ?
I'm creating an application token by calling : https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&grant_type=client_credentials
And with that token, I can't make api calls on the product catalogs which require catalog_management permission.